# Angular: how to scope a function call to directive instead of controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

`<my-dir ng-show="isVisible()"></my-dir>`

`isVisible` will call `isVisible` in the controller.

What if I want it to call `isVisible` inside the `my-dir` directive instead?

*Note: `my-dir` in my application is a tree control that recursively calls itself using `$compile` so there may be many of them nested inside each other. Using a singleton service may not work because of asynchronicity.*

**EDIT**: in retrospect I the correct answer was to create a filter for my directive.  What can I say, Angular is a different way of doing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a directive you have full control of the element. Just do this: `<my-dir check-visible="true"></my-dir>`

Then in the directive's link function you can just go: `if(attrs.checkVisible) isVisible();`

Then you can show or hide the element however you like.

Comment: That let's me get/set the attribute but doesn't actually hide the element.  I tried adding `if(!attrs.checkVisible) element.hide();` but that isn't hiding anything.

Comment: try element.remove();

Comment: Got it!  I am using https://github.com/mb21/JSONedit so the correct element to hide was actually: element[0].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode